# Best/Easiest Way to Implement Facebook login and ability to post on friend's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have tried several ways of implementing the Facebook login using the Facebook SDK for web. This somewhat worked where it appeared that I was able to sign in but was unable to do anything else. In addition, I am trying to post a comment on my friend's wall. What is the best way to implement this?

I looked at the facebook developer documentation and it gives a very basic summary of how to log in. However, this requires revealing my App ID/API Key in the page source. Is there a cleaner way of implementing a simple Facebook login without revealing this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is the Javascript SDK. A detailed tutorial can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/). Note that you only have to expose your App ID in the page source, not the API Key. This setup is fine, and secure.